# Why Java permits labels positioned far from a loop?

Tags: java, loops, syntax, goto

I was coding in JAVA and suddenly I wrote some code like this:

```
int x = 10;
boolean b = true;

l1: b = x > 1;

l2: while (b) {

    // some code
    break l2;
}
```

and to my surprise the code compiles and run properly. I'm doing nothing with my `l1` label but why does it compile correctly with this statement?

***I know that `goto` in java EXISTS but is not used ([Java Language Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)) but is there anyway that I can jump to it?***

Comment: Labels are used here for the case where you would want to break out of many nested loops. You wouldn't be able to break to `l1`.

Comment: Iirc, it's because you might have 2 nested loops, and you might want to break out to the outer one.

Comment: why do you think it should not work? If the syntax is correct it should compile.

Comment: @VishalK it doesn't do anything

Comment: My Mistake. it was wrong statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any statement can be labeled, but [they are only useful in conjunction with `break` or `continue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7):

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement; identifier statement labels are used with break (§14.15) or continue (§14.16) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

In other words, to be usable, the label needs to apply to a statement that contains a break or continue, which in turn can be a loop or, for `break` only, any block.

Comment: As I understand this, the reason why compilers don't complain about unreachable label is because Java designers want to have the possibility to make labels more usable in the future, possibly by using the "goto" statement which is currently reserved with no use.

Comment: the 2 kinds of breaks are very different. "break label" can break from any block, for example, ` abc:{ break abc; } `

Comment: @EyalSchneider I would be astonished if that were the case. Do you have any evidence? The real reason is far more likely because it would greatly complicate the grammar to only allow labels on certain kinds of statements.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to jump back to `l1` and continue execution.  As you say, `goto` is an unused keyword.  Labels are only useful for labeling loops to `break`/`continue`.

If you really want to "jump" to it, there are ways to do this through other programming techniques such as recursion.

i.e., if you wanted to jump back to `l1` instead of just breaking `l2`...

```
public void myMethod() {
    b = x > 1;

    while (b) {
        // some code
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

Be sure to add your return conditions though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come out of many loops, you can use labeled continue statement. A work around for your code will be like this.

```
int x = 10;
boolean b = true;

l1:
  for(int i=1;i>0;i--) { b = x > 1;

       l2: while (b) {
           // some code
           //break l2;
           i++;continue l1;
       }
  }
```